# ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

Tags: java, jdbc

I wrote a java servlet program but when i run it, It was showing the Exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

My code

```
DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "username", "pass");
```

I am using Oracle 10.2.0. I added also ojdbc14.jar and ojdbc14_g.jar.

When I give the below command to command line. I get `Error: Main method not found in class oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver`

Comment: Why are you running `java oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver`? You need to review a [jdbc tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html).

Comment: *I added also ojdbc14.jar and ojdbc14_g.jar* where did you add them, are you sure they are part of the Build path or inside *WEB-INF/lib* folder (the latter in case of java web applications)? Also, how are you trying to run this code?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I added from build path. from Add external jar. And there isnt lib folder under WEB-INF. Must I add jars to these folder?

Comment: If it is a web application, yes. I have to ask again: how are you trying to run this code?

Comment: Thank you Luiggi adding jars to WEB-INF/lib folder solves my problem. Its a simple web application for learning. I am using tomcat for run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I added also ojdbc14.jar and ojdbc14_g.jar

When adding third party libraries to your application, you must be sure they are in the Build Path of your application. In case of web applications, every third party library must be inside the *WEB-INF/lib* of the application so when deployed to the server (Tomcat, JBoss, etc.) they can be recognized and loaded when running your application.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to rectify (if running from command prompt)
Step 1- Copy the ojdbc6 jar file from 
C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\jdbc\lib (Note- this path may differ as per the installation).

Step 2- Paste the ojdbc6 jar file in the Location
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_45\lib\ext (Note- this path may differ as per the installation).

Step 3- Now run the programme java -cp .  . It should successfully run without any error.